# Why not scroll?

Tags: android, scrollview

I simply add a ScrollView out of a LinearLayout, whatever I change their width it did not scroll at all. I am a newbie here, anyone help me out? thanks in advance!

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/widget_box_action_1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/widget_box_action_2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/widget_box_action_3" />

         ...
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: do you really want to scroll horizontal?

Answer (score 0):

set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` of linearlayout, not to 1000dp.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to check why it is not scrolling try to set `android:layout_height="100dip"` for scrollview. the content which u want to display is enough that are easily shown on screen. If more content are there then scrollview will scroll. also set  `android:layout_width="fill_parent`" of linearlayout instead of 1000dp set to `fill_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you setup your ScrollView you are telling it to fill screen width with fill_parent. Try the below code. If I'm understanding correctly you want to scroll horizontally

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="1000dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="1000dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >
```